# Docker volume behaving differently with different images

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am new to docker and need to understand regarding docker volumes behavior

I am getting different results with nginx and jenkins

Scenario 1: With "nginx" image

```
# docker volume create testvol
testvol
# cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/testvol/_data/
# touch newfile1 newfile2
# ls
newfile1  newfile2

# docker run -it -v testvol:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx bash
# cd usr/share/nginx/html/
# ls
newfile1  newfile2
```

Here, inside container under /usr/share/nginx/html/ files are copied from volume(newfile1,newfile2) but the default nginx files erased(50x.html  index.html)

Scenario 2: with jenkins image

Using same volume testvol

```
# docker run -it -v testvol:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins bash
# cd /var/jenkins_home
# ls
copy_reference_file.log  newfile1  newfile2
```

Here, inside container the original file is preserved inside jenkins container(copy_reference_file.log) and files are copied from volume(newfile1,newfile2)

Why is this difference or am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The [Jenkins Docker image's source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) is on GitHub.  If you look at its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) that has the line towards the end

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

When you then

```
docker run ... jenkinsci/jenkinsci bash
```

the `bash` becomes the image's command, which gets [passed as an additional parameter to the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and Docker runs that combined command.  The [jenkins.sh](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh) script, in turn begins with

```sh
: "${JENKINS_HOME:="/var/jenkins_home"}"
: "${COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG:="${JENKINS_HOME}/copy_reference_file.log"}"
touch "${COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG}"
```

And that's why in your second example the file `copy_reference_file.log` exists.

When you create a container:

- If the Dockerfile declares a `VOLUME` and nothing else is mounted on that directory, Docker creates a new empty anonymous volume.
- If a named or anonymous volume (but not a bind mount) is being mounted into the container, and that volume is empty, the contents of the image are copied into the volume.
- The volume replaces the corresponding part of the container filesystem from here on out; reads and writes to that directory go to the volume (or bind-mounted host directory).

Volumes are *not* a "pass through" to the image; content gets copied to a volume only the very first time an empty volume is used.  If you take your example and re-run the `nginx` container with the same volume, you'll see the `copy_reference_file.log` still exists in the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So it means when we mount a non empty volume or bind mounts to the existing directory inside container . The non empty volume contents will override the  directory inside container.